# Start a script to Raspberry Pi without refresh the page

Tags: html, css, flask, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have a streaming server for my Raspberry Pi. I want to be able to control it with servos (pan and tilt) from the website. Therefore I want to start a python script, that starts when a botton is pressed at the website, without refreshing the page. Is there a way to do that? I'm using flask.

Comment: Forgot to mension that I use Python

Answer (score 0):

You would want to setup an endpoint in your flask app like:

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def indexpage():
    # Serve your index web page here
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')

@app.route("/runscript")
def runscript():
    # Do whatever you want here
    run_my_script()

app.run()
```

Then in your webpage have a form which sends a GET request to your app at the `runscript` endpoint.

```html
<form action="/runscript" method="get">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! When I use `app.send_static_file` I get "Not found". My code look like this:

Comment: `@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html') 

@app.route('/up/') 
def up():
 control.up()
 return render_template('index.html')    
 

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')    


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(Camera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', threaded=True)`